# I need to reorganise an array into a custom order

Tags: php, arrays

I have a multidimensional array of data and I need it sorted to match a certain order I have.
I have the following array:

Original Array:

```
$orig_array = array(
    'Grapes' => array("one", "two", "three"),
    'Apples' => array("one", "two", "three"),
    'Oranges' => array("one", "two", "three"),
    'Pears' => array("one", "two", "three"),
    'Watermelon' => array("one", "two", "three"),
    'Banana' => array("one", "two", "three")
);
```

Expected Array order :

```
$order = array(
    "Apples",
    "Watermelon",
    "Grapes",
    "Banana",
    "Pears",
    "Oranges"
);
```

What I tried:

```
usort($orig_array, function ($a, $b) use ($order) {
    $pos_a = array_search($a, $order);
    $pos_b = array_search($b, $order);
     return 0;
});

var_dump($orig_array);
```

but I have no result. Can someone please guide me in understanding how this function can be used so that I can get the expected result? I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: What is the criteria for sorting? That looks random to me.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "the criteria for sorting'?

Comment: What factor determines the order of the items?

Comment: please describe, what is the method, algorithm what you want to implement. Why "Watermelon" after Apples and then Grapes, so on...?

Comment: @CodeGodie: How would you like to have your result array? (Please update the question to include this information.) What's the logic behind the sorting process?

Comment: Its a custom order. We need the array to be organized in that order for now, but it might be sorted differently in the future.

Comment: lol... so what we need here, is some magic. But where that order comes from? is there ANY logic, behind that?

Comment: oh damn, i see.......

Comment: `$array = abracadabra_sort($array);` there we go OP.

Comment: No theres no logic. That order is made up. For example, lets say youre an admin looking at a database and you want it sorted in a specific order. You input the order you want it in, and you get your results.

Comment: @CodeGodie "*We need the array to be organized in that order for now*" then you have it how you want! So what is your actual question?

Comment: this is an unanswered question try to do it manually if u want an custom order :D

Comment: The question is pretty clear guys. He wants it in a CUSTOM order. For e.g. like $order.

Comment: @CodeGodie: Well, PHP isn't telepathic and can't read your minds and magically sort it in a "custom order" ;) There has to be a logic to, you know... implement it.

Comment: @CodeGodie: I'll go again: how do you expect `$orig_array` to look like after the sorting has been performed (in order specified in `$order`)?

Comment: @KunalGupta Feel free to provide an answer to sort an array in an order without any reason, criteria, or rationale. You could make a script to order as it is in the question, as the OP said that's how they want it, but you would simply be making a script manually order it that way, and then any additional data in the array would not be catered for. The question is impossible to answer atm.

Comment: See my answer. I figured out what you need.

Comment: The problem is that, you are do not want to **sorting**. Instead, you want to **reorganize based on `$order` array**

Comment: @lolka_bolka's answer is the required answer I suppose.

Comment: Exactly.It should not be called **sort**. It should be **reorganise based on `$order`**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If i understood, you have an `$order` array, what determinates the order of your array, and you want to reorganize your `$orig_array` based on this `$order` array:

**My answer:**

```
$orig_array = array(
    'Grapes' => array("one", "two", "three"),
    'Apples' => array("one", "two", "three"),
    'Oranges' => array("one", "two", "three"),
    'Pears' => array("one", "two", "three"),
    'Watermelon' => array("one", "two", "three"),
    'Banana' => array("one", "two", "three")
);

$order = array(
    "Apples",
    "Watermelon",
    "Grapes",
    "Banana",
    "Pears",
    "Oranges"
);

foreach ($order as $key) {

    $new_array[$key] = $orig_array[$key];
}

var_dump($new_array);
```

Output is:

```
array
  'Apples' => 
    array
      0 => string 'one' (length=3)
      1 => string 'two' (length=3)
      2 => string 'three' (length=5)
  'Watermelon' => 
    array
      0 => string 'one' (length=3)
      1 => string 'two' (length=3)
      2 => string 'three' (length=5)
  'Grapes' => 
    array
      0 => string 'one' (length=3)
      1 => string 'two' (length=3)
      2 => string 'three' (length=5)
  'Banana' => 
    array
      0 => string 'one' (length=3)
      1 => string 'two' (length=3)
      2 => string 'three' (length=5)
  'Pears' => 
    array
      0 => string 'one' (length=3)
      1 => string 'two' (length=3)
      2 => string 'three' (length=5)
  'Oranges' => 
    array
      0 => string 'one' (length=3)
      1 => string 'two' (length=3)
      2 => string 'three' (length=5)
```

**EDIT:** As Amal Mulari says in my answers comment:

```
$new_array = array_combine($order, $orig_array); 
var_dump($new_array);
//More elegant, 1 line solution.
```

**NOTE:** This solution is works only, if the elements of arrays are the same! If there are not the same, for example `'Apples' => array ("two", "three"); and 'Melone' => array('four', 'five');` This solution is not works as expected!

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, you might as well do: `array_combine($order, $orig_array);`.

Comment: You are right, i've just lost in the question already :) I updated my code. Let's add yours as an answer.

Comment: @AmalMurali Nooooooo, that blindly combines the first key from the `$order` array with the first value of `$orig_array`, etc. Here all values are the same so it looks like it works, but I would assume that that is not the case in the real situation so you would loose the relation between your keys and your values.

Comment: @jeroen: The question was unclear to me; that's why I specifically included "*If I understand the question correctly*" in my comment :P

Comment: @jeroen: good catch, you are right. I do not test that.

Comment: Guys i apologize for my unclear question. I am glad you were able to understand what I was trying to ask. Your answers pointed me in the right direction. Thank you.

Comment: Ok, but be carefull, i've edited my answer, so read the NOTE at the end of my answer.